# wxPython message dialog won't work with function

Tags: python, string, unicode, wxpython, messagedialog

I'm new to Python and just started writing a basic GUI program with wxPython. I have a series of text boxes where the user enters data and then they click a submit button.

The submit button triggers a `getvalue` method for each box (it looks like `a=self.textbox1.GetValue()`).

The there is a function that simply reads `answer=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h`.

Then finally there's the `wx.MessageDialog(self, answer, Title, wx.OK | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)` that prints the answer in a `msg` dialog.

But instead of printing the sum of the numbers, it just prints them in a series.

I was messing around and replaced the variables in the answer function with actual integers and it gives me an error that says:

> String or Unicode type required

I can't really think of any way to fix it since I only have like two days experience with Python.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`GetValue()` gives you the string value of what was typed.

You want to convert the strings to integers before trying to sum them.

```
a = int(self.textbox1.GetValue())
```

Comment: Now it gives `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: Actually that was another part of the code, fixed that, but the message dialog is still giving the same error after I took int values of variables.

Comment: You have to convert answer back to a string to display it. `str(answer)`